# MySql - using dynamic table names in one query

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

**cars**

- id
- name
- color

**bicycles**

- id
- name
- number_of_gearshift

I need a central index table of this tables in my mysql database and a unique id for them. Something like this:

**items**

- id
- table_name

Lets say, the id in the items-table is the same as in the corresponding table:

**items**

```
id | table_name
 1 | cars
 2 | cars
 3 | bicycles
 4 | cars
```

**cars**

```
id | name        | color
 1 | Peugeot     | red
 2 | BMW         | green  
 4 | Nissan      | blue
```

**bicycles**

```
id | name      | number_of_gearshift
 3 | Stevens   | 24
```

My question - the following situation:
I have the ID (for example XXX) of an item. Now I want to get the data of this item, by only one query. Something like this (I know, that will not work):

```
SELECT table2.*
FROM (SELECT table_name FROM items WHERE id = XXX) AS table2
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Please add your expected output so that it would be more clear.

Comment: The expected output is the data of table2 and depends on the table itself. So if XXX=1, the output would be: "1, peugeot, red". If XXX=3, the output would be "3, Stevens, 24"

Comment: I'd use a different table structure from scratch combining the two tables. The only difference is the color/number_of_gearshift so make this two column null by default and set a value for the firs if it's a car or the second if it's a bike. You can also add a type column (bike/car) but it is not necessary at all.

Comment: That was just an example. out in the wild, the tables have more columns (for example number_of_doors, number_of_airbags, etc.) and there are more tables like motorcycles, boats, trucks, etc with different columns. I can't combine that, because I would have a hugh number of NULL-Value columns for each record and even some columns have the same name, but different datatypes (for example a bicyle has a weight <20kg, so we can use decimal(3,1), but a boat has >1000kg and no need for decimals, so we can use Smallint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use a dynamic sql query to achieve this.

```
set @query = null;
set @id = 3;/*change according to requirement*/
SET @tn := (select `table_name` from items where id =  @id);

set @query = concat('select * from ',@tn,' where id = ',@id);

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Change the value of `@id` according to your requirement.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37038b/1)

Comment: Oh sorry, the questions is not answered yet. I need a query to get ALL rows, not only a specific one (@id). .

Comment: Then how do you want the output??